# $x^3+2x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ or not.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was solving the CSIR NET problems there i encounter a problem as:
 $x^3+2x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ or not. Firstly, Eisenstein criterion cannot be applicable to this problem Secondly, replacing $(x+1),(x+2)$ in place of $x$ does not reduce to a polynomial where i can apply the eisenstein criterion. Is there any different method to attack these type of problems in a short time.

Comment: If it is reducible, then it must have a root in $\mathbb{Z}$, since the degree is $3$.

Comment: It's irreducible modulo $2$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it was reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, it would have to have a linear factor with integer coefficients, and hence a rational root.

But by the rational root test, the only possible rational roots are $\pm 1$, neither of which is an actual root.

Comment: yes, now i got it rational root test will be best way to think this problem... thank you sir